# Doubt about the validity of a question's answers in MathSE - set of all sets with a given cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory

The question I am referring to is the following: [Showing that the class of all sets of a particular cardinality is not a set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120635/showing-that-the-class-of-all-sets-of-a-particular-cardinality-is-not-a-set)

OP presented his proof of the fact stated in the title by assuming the existence of such a set (which he calls $T_h$ where $h$ is the cardinal number in question) and by reconstructing Russel's Paradox, i.e. "the set $U$ of all sets does not exist". In doing so he simply says "let $a$ be any set" and the proceeds in showing that $a \in \cup T_h$ thus concluding that $\cup T_h = U$. However it seems to me that we are implicitly assuming that $U$ exists and then we are just proving that $T_h \subseteq U$.

I may be at fault so I am asking if OP's argument is correct or not, especially because no one else pointed this fallacy out under his question.

---

As for the proof of the statement, I guess that we can reproduce Russel's argument:

> Suppose $H:=\{X: |X|=h\}$ exists for some cardinal number $h$ (I shall use the definition of cardinal numbers as initial ordinal numbers). Define $R:=\{X \in \cup H: X \notin X\}$, then by Russel's argument $R$ can not belong to $\cup H$ (otherwise it would have to either belong or not belong to itself, which is impossible). However, we can always define a set from $h$ by replacing the least element with $R$ so that the new set $h_R$ has cardinality $h$. Therefore $h_R \in H$ and thus $R \in \cup H$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The argument shows that $\cup T_h = U$, not $T_h = U$. By the axiom of union, if $T_h$ were a set, then $U$ would be as well. But we know $U$ is not a set by the axiom of regularity. So $T_h$ is not a set.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo on my end (now fixed), but still I don't think you can simply say "let $a$ be any set then" because you can only work with elements of an embedding set. For instance, when an exercise is given in which it is stated that "let a,b,c be sets ..." you need to assume that these sets are given in a family (which also assures that if $a=b$ you can still work with them being distinct objects).

Comment: @MatteoMenghini You can in fact reason with arbitrary sets. For example, "For any set $a$, $a \notin a$" is a provable statement. What you can't do is say all the sets with some property are in some set.

Comment: @aschepler Yet I do not see your example as equal to what the OP in the question I mentioned does. In fact, I may interpret your statement as “if I am given a set $a$ I can prove/disprove that $a\in a$”. However a specific set has to be given to me, then the generality of the argument may apply to any other set is given to me, but I wouldn’t say that I proved/disproved it for any set.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini No, that's not what I claimed. More exactly, $\forall a (\lnot (a \in a))$ is provable from ZF. For an even simpler example, "For any set $a$, $\{a\}$ is a set" follows directly from the pair axiom.

Comment: @aschepler I think there is some sort of linguistic fact that I am not getting at. I do not understand why we can say that a property holds for all sets without having the set of all sets. In other words, what is a property if not the set of all the sets with such property? ù

Comment: A property is not a set. It's a formula φ. If φ(x) is true for the set x. Then we say x has the property φ

Comment: @MatteoMenghini It is perfectly possible to make a statement about all sets with X property within ZFC. In fact, most of the axioms of ZFC are such statements. What ZFC does not allow is stating that the collection of all sets with X property is a *set*. Instead, it only asserts the existence of a subset of some existing set $A$ consisting of all elements of $A$ with X property.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you very much for the comment. I guess that what I lack is knowledge about ZFC. Unfortunately I have only studied Halmos' book but I plan to study more set theory in the future.

Comment: You might also want to study first order logic, in order to understand the role of formulas.

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you have any suggested reading?

Comment: Kunen has a book " The Foundation of Mathematics" which, if you've worked with Halmos, should be around the appropriate level.

Answer (score -1):

You are right that the proof in that question fails to justify its claim that $\bigcup T_h$ is a set.

The union axiom says that if $\{T_h\}_h$ is a set, then $\cup \{T_h\}_h = \bigcup_h T_h$ is a set. But knowing that all the $T_h$ are sets doesn't tell us that $\{T_h\}$ is a set. (If it did, we could get to Russel's paradox just by saying every set $x$ is a set, so $\{x\}$ is the set of all sets!)

(Also, if the proof were valid, it would only disprove the claim that $T_h$ is a set for every cardinality $h$, showing that $T_h$ is not a set for at least one cardinality $h$. Your proof shows the stronger claim that for any cardinality $h$, $T_h$ is not a set.)

Comment: Just a clarification: following Halmos, I interpreted $\bigcup T_h$ a the union of all the sets belonging to $T_h$ rather than the union of all the $T_h$'s for different $h$'s. Is this the convention you are also following?

Comment: I meant $\cup \{T_h\}_h = \bigcup_h T_h$, which are two informal ways of saying the union of all the $T_h$ sets. More strictly, the unique set $U$ such that $\forall x(x \in U \leftrightarrow \exists h (\operatorname{IsCardinal}(h) \land x \in T_h))$. (And of course $U$ would then equal the universal set.)

Comment: @aschepler In axiomatic set theory, $\cup T_h$ denotes the union of all elements of $T_h$, not the union over all $h$ of sets of the form $T_h$. The union axiom says: If $X$ is a set, then $\cup X$ is a set.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I admit the "indexed" union $\bigcup_h$ is confusing here, and I've removed it from my answer. I meant to use $\cup$ and $\bigcup_h$ differently, analagously to the difference between $\operatorname{Sum} \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$.